# Django app takes only a part of requested URL

Tags: django, http, url, post, get

I have a strange issue in my project. When my AJAX sends POST request to uri '/api/login/', Django goes to '/login/' uri. When I try to get a page '/api/login/' using GET method, Django goes to function, that is relevant to '/api/login/'.

I can't understand where is a problem. Why POST methods don't see '/api/' substring in the request URL.

Do you know where a problem can be? This bug is only on one server. On localhost and on another hosting it works properly.

url.py

```
    urlpatterns = [
      url(r'^api/login/', ApiLoginView.as_view()),
      url(r'^', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'))
      ....]
```

ajax (react)

```
if(form.valid()){
            axios.post('/api/login/', {
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: crsf,
                email: email,
                password: password,
                remember_me: remember_me
            }).then(function (response) {
                if(!response.data.user || response.data.user == "false"){
                    //
                }
                if(response.data.user != "false"){
                    ReactDOM.render(<Hello username={response.data.user} />, document.getElementById('root'));
                }
            }).catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
```

Thank you.

Comment: You'll need to show us your code, it's impossible to solve a bug without seeing your code. Show us your javascript with the AJAX request and show us the relevant urls.py.

Comment: updated question

Comment: are you sure the form is posted via the ajax call and not via the default html form submit? (which would probably go to the current page's url, i.e. `/login`) Asking this because to submit a form using Ajax, you need to make sure you prevent the default behaviour of the submit button using `e.preventDefault()` on the click event. You can check by setting a breakpoint on the line `axios.post`

Comment: Yes, I'm sure, all is working on my localhost & my hosting. But on the second hosting it doesn't work... Also, this form hasn't URL in action field... `<form id="form_login" class="needs-validation was-validated" novalidate="novalidate">`

Comment: a form without URL in action field gets posted to the URL of the page itself by default, so that doesn't mean anything. the important thing is the button to submit the form, check that you reach the breakpoint when clicking it before your server receives the post. It's the only way this can happen.